# How to make MSBuild to NOT stop on error on .NET solution

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I'm working on a custom build server setup tailored to the team needs.
It should automatically build our .net solutions.
I'm doing my best to not change anything in the .sln or project files.

The obvious build tool for the job is the `msbuild`. I've got it as far as to actually successfully compile our solutions from .sln files.

Next step is testing the scenario when some of solution's projects are broken. And here I encountered a strange difference in behavior between `devenv` and `msbuild` in following situation. There are 3 projects, where 2nd depends on 1st, and 3rd is independent and broken. `devenv` compiles 1st and 2nd and fails the 3rd, as expected; `msbuild` compiles 1st, fails 3rd and - unexpectedly - doesn't try the 2nd.

Example solution (4 files: Complete.sln, 1.csproj, 2.csproj, 3.csproj)

```
--- 1.csproj
<Project ToolsVersion="Current" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <FileUpgradeFlags>
    </FileUpgradeFlags>
    <UpgradeBackupLocation>
    </UpgradeBackupLocation>
    <OldToolsVersion>2.0</OldToolsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="Build">
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Project 1" />
  </Target>
</Project>
--- 2.csproj
<Project ToolsVersion="Current" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <FileUpgradeFlags>
    </FileUpgradeFlags>
    <UpgradeBackupLocation>
    </UpgradeBackupLocation>
    <OldToolsVersion>2.0</OldToolsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="Build">
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Project 2" />
  </Target>
</Project>
--- 3.csproj
<Project ToolsVersion="Current" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <FileUpgradeFlags>
    </FileUpgradeFlags>
    <UpgradeBackupLocation>
    </UpgradeBackupLocation>
    <OldToolsVersion>2.0</OldToolsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="Build">
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Project 3" />
    <Error Text="Build failed" />
  </Target>
</Project>
--- Complete.sln

Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 16
VisualStudioVersion = 16.0.29709.97
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "1", "1.csproj", "{AA88BE9A-5006-4CCE-8871-A67F413DBADF}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "2", "2.csproj", "{BAF51480-4B90-454A-96F5-E63A05A486EF}"
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
        {AA88BE9A-5006-4CCE-8871-A67F413DBADF} = {AA88BE9A-5006-4CCE-8871-A67F413DBADF}
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "3", "3.csproj", "{12C30CFB-7387-4CD2-81D4-87E14209C408}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {AA88BE9A-5006-4CCE-8871-A67F413DBADF}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {AA88BE9A-5006-4CCE-8871-A67F413DBADF}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86
        {BAF51480-4B90-454A-96F5-E63A05A486EF}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {BAF51480-4B90-454A-96F5-E63A05A486EF}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86
        {12C30CFB-7387-4CD2-81D4-87E14209C408}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {12C30CFB-7387-4CD2-81D4-87E14209C408}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {75E95C15-489D-4D3F-82CA-735FB7B88910}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Console output from "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019" is like following:

```
e>devenv /Build Debug Complete.sln

Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.4.3.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
1>------ Build started: Project: 1, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
2>------ Build started: Project: 3, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
1>  Project 1
2>  Project 3
2>C:\temp\msbuild\TestSolution\Complete\3.csproj(11,2): error : Build failed
3>------ Build started: Project: 2, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
3>  Project 2
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>msbuild Complete.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x86 /m
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 23.01.2020 11:10:38.
     1>Project "c:\temp\msbuild\TestSolution\Complete\Complete.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
     1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
         Building solution configuration "Debug|x86".
     1>Project "c:\temp\msbuild\TestSolution\Complete\Complete.sln" (1) is building "c:\temp\msbuild\TestSolution\Complete\1.cs
       proj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
     2>Build:
         Project 1
     2>Done Building Project "c:\temp\msbuild\TestSolution\Complete\1.csproj" (default targets).
     1>Project "c:\temp\msbuild\TestSolution\Complete\Complete.sln" (1) is building "c:\temp\msbuild\TestSolution\Complete\3.cs
       proj" (3) on node 2 (default targets).
     3>Build:
         Project 3
     3>c:\temp\msbuild\TestSolution\Complete\3.csproj(11,5): error : Build failed
     3>Done Building Project "c:\temp\msbuild\TestSolution\Complete\3.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
     1>Done Building Project "c:\temp\msbuild\TestSolution\Complete\Complete.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

       "c:\temp\msbuild\TestSolution\Complete\Complete.sln" (default target) (1) ->
       "c:\temp\msbuild\TestSolution\Complete\3.csproj" (default target) (3) ->
       (Build target) ->
         c:\temp\msbuild\TestSolution\Complete\3.csproj(11,5): error : Build failed

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.65
```

Please notice in `msbuild` output the `Project 2` message is missing.

Is there a (non-intrusive) way to make `msbuild` continue compiling other projects?

The best I came up till now is creating a `Directory.Solution.targets` in some folder upwards from `Complete.sln` (see [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#search-scope)) with following content.

```
<Project>
  <Target Name="SetSkip">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Update="*">
        <SkipNonexistentProjects>Build</SkipNonexistentProjects>
      </ProjectReference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="BuildAll" DependsOnTargets="SetSkip">
    <CallTarget Targets="Build"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Note `SkipNonexistentProjects` is set to `Build`, not `True`. When set to `True` the 2nd project is skipped with `Skipping project "2.csproj.metaproj" because it was not found.`.

And then calling `msbuild` with `/t:BuildAll` instead of `/t:Build`. But I'd need to do this for <s>every possible solution and</s> every possible target, and I'd really like some better way, maybe a command line switch I wasn't able to find yet (`/p:ContinueOnError=true;StopOnFirstFailure=false;SkipNonexistentProjects=true` doesn't help).

**UPDATE** improved my workaround: now only a single additional file in a root folder is needed.

Comment: IMHO the behaviour of continuing building is usually unhelpful: it just means the original error is harder to spot... and most of the rest of the errors are only there are a result of the first error.

Comment: @Richard In case there is a problem in project 2, I wont see it until project 3 - completely unrelated to 1 or 2 - compiles again. I don't think this is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This answer quotes my workaround in the question itself, to improve its visibility (as suggested in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59876630/how-to-make-msbuild-to-not-stop-on-error-on-net-solution#comment105975807_59892250) to another answer).*

The best I came up till now is creating a `Directory.Solution.targets` in some folder upwards from `Complete.sln` (see [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#search-scope)) with following content.

```xml
<Project>
  <Target Name="SetSkip">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Update="*">
        <SkipNonexistentProjects>Build</SkipNonexistentProjects>
      </ProjectReference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="BuildAll" DependsOnTargets="SetSkip">
    <CallTarget Targets="Build"/>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="RebuildAll" DependsOnTargets="SetSkip">
    <CallTarget Targets="Rebuild"/>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="CleanAll" DependsOnTargets="SetSkip">
    <CallTarget Targets="Clean"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Note `SkipNonexistentProjects` is set to `Build`, not `True`. When set to `True` the 2nd project is skipped with `Skipping project "2.csproj.metaproj" because it was not found.`.

And then calling `msbuild` with `/t:BuildAll` instead of `/t:Build` builds everything it can, as expected.

This is a *good enough* solution for me, although I would still prefer some way without defining alternate Build/Rebuild targets.

Answer (score 0):

> How to make MSBuild to NOT stop on error on .NET solution

The answer is **NO** as it looks like one issue about msbuild. So we can only have workaround instead of solution...

I can reproduce same issue in my machine with VS2019 and msbuild 16.0. Since it all works well using devenv, I think you can post one issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues) to Msbuild Team. (I tried with several msbuild properties but they don't work, so i think this issue)

And here's some temporary workarounds:

1.If you don't have too many projects in this solution, you can use `target` switch to build specific projects with specific order, check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-specific-targets-in-solutions-by-using-msbuild-exe?view=vs-2017).

For me, I use command like `msbuild Library.sln -target:LibraryA;LibraryB;LibraryC  /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU" -m` and then msbuild will build `LibraryB`.

2.If you have many projects in same solution, you may create a custom build script `build.proj` file in solution folder with content like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="CustomBuild">
<MSBuild Projects="LibraryA\LibraryA.vbproj" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform)"/>
<MSBuild Projects="LibraryB\LibraryB.vbproj" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform)"/>
<MSBuild Projects="LibraryC\LibraryC.vbproj" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform)"/>
```

Then use command like msbuild build.proj /p:Configuration=xx;Platform=xx to build these projects.

You can try these workarounds temporarily, or you can use devenv command for your build. But for the issue itself, the solution should one fix from msbuild team if I don't misunderstand... Hope all above helps :)

Comment: The problem with your workaround is, what happens if a new project is added? I don't want to manually adjust anything at all on the "build server". In that case I will stick with my workaround.

Comment: My workaround do need manual edit if new project is added :-(. Please consider adding your workaround in answer instead of in question, so that more members can see the useful info! Check [can I answer ...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), just a reminder :)