# Set msbuild OutputPath conditioned on project name

Tags: msbuild

I'm trying to improve a build-server setup for .NET solutions. The build is done using `msbuild solution.sln /p:OutputPath="$pwd/build"` and an additional `Directory.Solution.targets` to work around a quirk of msbuild (from [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59876630/how-to-make-msbuild-to-not-stop-on-error-on-net-solution), see its content below). Now we've decided to move our tests to separate projects so that the test dlls and their dependencies don't land in the OutputPath. Usually this wouldn't be a problem, but for historical reasons every single project in the solution has its OutputPath set to `..\..\`. This is why I'm overriding it when calling `msbuild`. But now I need to only override it for some of the projects - and I can't figure out how.

The project structure right now looks like this.

```
app/
    sources/
            Complete.sln
            Proj1/
                  proj1.csproj
            Proj1.Test/
                  proj1.test.csproj
```

Building the solution from Visual Studio by a developer results in this (only showing new files), which is fine.

```
app/
    proj1.exe
    sources/Proj1.Tests/bin/Release/
                                    proj1.exe
                                    proj1.tests.dll
```

But building it with `msbuild Complete.sln /p:OutputPath="$pwd/build" /t:BuildAll` results in following.

```
app/build/
    proj1.exe
    proj1.tests.dll
```

Is there a way without changing solution or project files to get the following?

```
app/build/
    proj1.exe
app/tests/
    proj1.exe
    proj1.tests.dll
```

I.e. I want to set the `OutputPath` for every `*.Tests.csproj` to `/tests`, and for every other project to `/build`.

**Alternatively**, is there a way to call `msbuild Complete.sln` in such a way it builds either all the projects from that solution with names that don't end with "Tests" or only those that do?

The `Directory.Solution.targets` mentioned above (using it for [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59876630/how-to-make-msbuild-to-not-stop-on-error-on-net-solution)) looks like following.

```xml
<Project>
  <Target Name="SetSkip">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Update="*">
        <SkipNonexistentProjects>Build</SkipNonexistentProjects>
      </ProjectReference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="BuildAll" DependsOnTargets="SetSkip">
    <CallTarget Targets="Build"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

**UPDATE** since the number of files grows, for easier testing I've created a [repository](https://github.com/TymurGubayev/TestMSBuild/).

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the following to `Directory.Build.targets` (I have not tested it, but it should work):

```
   <PropertyGroup>
      <OutputPath Condition="'$(BuildOutputPath)' != ''
          and !$(MSBuildProjectName.EndsWith('.Test'))">$(BuildOutputPath)</OutputPath>
      <OutputPath Condition="'$(TestOutputPath)' == ''
         and $(MSBuildProjectName.EndsWith('.Test'))">$(TestOutputPath)</OutputPath>
   </PropertyGroup>
```

Then invoke msbuild like so:

```
msbuild Complete.sln /p:TestOutputPath="$pwd\tests" /p:BuildOutputPath="$pwd\build"
```

There would be other options, like putting the required `build` or `tests` paths directly in the properties.

Comment: I think the condition for TestOutputPath should be `!=` too. And unfortunately, this doesn't work (or I'm doing something wrong).

Comment: I've created a repository with a test-case: https://github.com/TymurGubayev/TestMSBuild/